Add sequence in odoo
i try to add an simple counter by following this example:
https://www.odoo.com/de_DE/forum/hilfe-1/how-do-i-create-a-field-with-a-running-count-72390
If i try to activate the module i get the error "the field sequence" is not available.
And if i change the code in the python file from
    _columns = {
    'sequence':fields.Char("Sequence", readonly=True)
    }

to
    sequence = fields.Char(string="Sequence", readonly=True)

i get a parse error that is something wrong in:
<record id="debitor_counter_sequence_type" model="ir.sequence.type">
<field name="name">Label of your sequence code.</field>
<field name="code">debitor.counter.sequence.code</field>   <!-- Unique sequence code.-->
</record>

can anyone help me?
Update:
I get no errors but it always shows the default value.
I changed the code to:
DebitCard.py
from odoo import models, fields, api

class DebitCard(models.Model):
    _name="debit.card"
    _description="Debit Card"
    
    name = fields.Char(string="Debit Card Datev Sequence", default="-1", readonly=True)

@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('debit.card.sequence.code')
    result = super(DebitCard,self).create(vals)
    return result

I added a xml file for the sequence:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <data>
        <record id="debit_card_datev_sequence" model="ir.sequence">
            <field name="name">Debit Card Datev Sequence</field>
            <field name="code">debit.card.sequence.code</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>

And i added the sequence in settings->technical-sequence:


For which Odoo version did you try it?

Why am i asking? That solution in the help forum is for stone age Odoo versions (8.0 or less). A lot has changed, so that solution won't work in newer versions.

For version 17. I am not familiar with odoo and it do not works like a “normal“ website. The manual do not help me because my english is not the best...

Check the sale order sequence used with name field
